# Amount parallel processing Simple Queue Service (SQS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am using Spring Cloud to consume Simple Queue Service (SQS). I have the following configurations for parallel processing:

```
@Bean
public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(50);
    return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor) {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    factory.setWaitTimeOut(20);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

    return factory;
}
```

I need to process 50 messages in 50 threads (configuration in the bean SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor), but is processing only 10 messages in parallel (maxNumberOfMessages returned from SQS)

How can I process 50 messages instead 10?

Comment: So it's processing 10 messages in 50 threads (in parallel), or its processing 10 messages in total? You have set the `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);` so if it's processing 10 messages times 50 threads in parallel, then up that number to 50? *edit* nevermind, i see in the docs, that max messages pr. request is 10. You need to pool in more threads, if you're running into bottlenecking.

Comment: In the docs the maximum number of messages returned per request is 10.
So it's processing 10 messages in 50 threads. When the processing of the 10 messages ends, a new request is made.
I'd like to make 5 requests in the SQS queue that would result in 50 messages being processed in 50 threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

It's necessary to annotate the method with `@Async`, change `deletionPolicy` to `NEVER`, and delete the message when finalizing execution.

In this way, the queue consume will respect the configured number of threads. For example, if you have 50 threads, will make 5 requests in the SQS queue (10 messages per request), thus processing a total of 50 messages in parallel.

The code looks like this:

```
@Async
@SqsListener(value = "sqsName", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
public void consume(String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    //your code

    acknowledgment.acknowledge().get(); //To delete message from queue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be into specific numbers (like 50 messages for 50 threads) too much. Try performance testing it instead (build something to push the expected number of messages in peak-hours to the queue, and let your service handle them, to see if it bottlenecks).

As per your actual question, you can't. AWS SQS simply doesnt support fetching more than 10 messages pr. request. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html for reference. (it's in the 1st paragraph).

Comment: I have a large volume of messages. So 10 messages at a time is not enough.

In the docs really each request returns only 10 messages, but I would like to make more than one request to the SQS queue. For example, I would like to make 5 requests for SQS, resulting in a total of 50 messages, where these 50 would be processed in the 50 threds.

Comment: Ahh i see your point. I thought the executor was doing polling-requests concurrently, but i see it's used in the container that's processing the actual messages. I don't have the knowledge about spring-cloud-aws to come with a proper suggestion on the fly, without fiddling with it myself. Sorry.